# Flask-Migrate sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Пытаюсь создать БД через модели на flask.

models.py

```py
class Permission(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'permission'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': Config.SCHEMA}

    id = db.Column(db.String(64), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(64))

    role_permissions_perm = db.relationship('RolePermission', backref='permission_role_permission', lazy='select')


class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'role'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': Config.SCHEMA}

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True)
    add_who = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    add_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    edit_who = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    edit_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)

    role_permissions_role = db.relationship('RolePermission', backref='role_role_permission', lazy='select')
    role_user_role = db.relationship('UserRole', backref='role_role_user', lazy='select')


class RolePermission(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'role_permission'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': Config.SCHEMA}

    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('role.id'), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    permission_id = db.Column(db.String(64), db.ForeignKey('permission.id'), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
```

при вызове *flask db migrate* получаю ошибку:

**sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'role_permission.permission_id' could not find table 'permission' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'**

permission я создаю раньше и уже затем ссылаюсь на нее, почему он sqlalchemy выдает такую ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, потому что вместо

```py
permission_id = db.Column(db.String(64), db.ForeignKey('permission.id'),
                          primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
```

должно быть

```py
permission_id = db.Column(db.String(64), db.ForeignKey(Config.SCHEMA + '.permission.id'), 
                          primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
```

проблема была в том, что я пытался ссылаться на таблицу, без указания схемы (по умолчанию в postgres, например, это public), но сама таблица была создана в схеме, которая указана в `Config.SCHEMA`

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что в разных таблицах у вас колонка id заданы разными типами данных: одна - String(64), а другая - Integer